# Angular: Send email to gmail email address without nodejs/email server

Tags: angular, email, gmail

I'm trying to build a contact-us form, where the user enters their name and a message on a web page, and I want the information to be simply sent to a gmail email address.

Is there a way to send the email to a gmail email address without setting up any email servers? I was looking at nodemailer and emailjs, but I think they require having a node.js server or some sort of email server.

Is there something as straightforward as just sending a POST request to a URL that sends the email, using the Gmail API?

I have built the web page using angular 6.

Answer (score 0):

you will definitely need a mail server, you can configure from your backend or use third-party mail server like sendgrid and using their API service.